# Can I use schematron to validate that date ranges don't overlap in an xml file?

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron

Imagine I have a simple xml file:

```
<intervals>
  <range from="2001-12-17T09:30:47Z" to="2001-12-19T11:35:16Z" />
  <range from="2002-12-17T09:30:47Z" to="2002-12-19T11:35:16Z" />
<intervals>
```

I would like to ensure that the date ranges given do not overlap. I can do this in code, obviously, but ideally I would like to provide a validation package to go with my xml schema to validate some business rules.

Can I use a schematron to validate that the ranges do not overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO Schematron is the tool for your problem. Just use the implementation for XPath 2.0 that allows data typing. Then you only have to test an assertion. Something like `<assert test="@from &lt; @to"/>`

See : http://www.schematron.com/implementation.html

Concerning overlap : you can code an XSLT function that return a boolean in your schematron schema and call it from your test attribute.

Schematron with XSLT function embedded :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fct="localFunctions" queryBinding="xslt2"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <ns prefix="fct" uri="localFunctions"/>
    <pattern>
        <rule context="intervals">
            <assert test="fct:checkOverlaping((),range)" >OVERLAPING</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
    <xsl:function name="fct:checkOverlaping" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="currentEndDate" as="xs:dateTime?"/>
        <xsl:param name="ranges" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(exists($currentEndDate))">
                <xsl:variable name="orderedRanges" as="node()*">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$ranges">
                        <xsl:sort select="@from"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="fct:checkOverlaping(xs:dateTime($orderedRanges[position()=1]/@to),$orderedRanges[position()>1])"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="
                    if (not(exists($ranges))) then true() else 
                    if ($currentEndDate > $ranges[position()=1]/@from) then false() else 
                    fct:checkOverlaping($ranges[position()=1]/@to,$ranges[position()>1])
                    "/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
</schema>
```

Use the following implementation : http://www.schematron.com/tmp/iso-schematron-xslt2.zip which implements `allow-foreign` and uses XPath 2.0. When this parameter `allow-foreign` is set to true, the implementation will embed the function above.

How the function works : first loop (currentEndDate not set) the `range` elements are sorted by `from` date. Other recursive loop (after sorting) : test if the `to` date of the first range is before the from date of the second date and go on for the next if it is true (otherwise false and stop).

Comment: This looks brilliant.  Now I have to solve the problem of how to make it work in .net, but that's another story...

Comment: Consider using saxon (https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.3/SaxonHE9-3-0-5N-setup.exe/download), it provides a .net implementation of XSLT 2.0.